# Twitter Bootstrap 4 column grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Does Bootstrap 3 offer a 4 column grid?  Basically .col-md-2.  I think it is only 1, 3, 4, 6, 8 , 12?

If no 2, is there some other way to build a 4 column grid?

Comment: Im a little unclear what you are asking for but the documentation is here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have it in reverse

```
class="col-md-2"
```

Would mean you wanted 6 columns on the page.

The number after the 'column - size' determines the width of the column (each number represents one column) so the larger the number the wider the element on the page, not the amount of columns you want on the page.

So in order to make a 4 column grid your css class should be:

```
class="col-md-3"
```

so counting by up the widths 3+3+3+3 = 12